# Microsoft Framework Update (KB4054981) Causing Issues With Crystal Reports 13 Not Displaying

Tags: windows, vb.net, crystal-reports

Per the title, I am having issues getting a Crystal Report to display on my website. Here are the necessary details:

- Microsoft security and quality update for framework 4.6/4.7 was applied to a server the night prior. We know that this is the culprit because once the update was rolled back, with no other solutions applied to the server code, the website was displaying Crystal Report pages correctly.
- Team verified that the aspnet_client/system_web folder that the server was looking for was present in the website directory and had the necessary files within. Also checked user computers to see if their computers were looking for similar files.
- Team restarted IIS and verified that necessary permissions were granted for users to the crystal report files.
- Team was receiving the "bobj is undefined" error when locally debugging until the specific aspnet_client/system_web folder was added to the solution.
- Team was receiving errors surrounding the crv.js and style.css files not being found until the specific aspnet_client/system_web folder was added to the solution.
- Team has tried to add specific < SectionGroup > and < Section > code for Crystal Reports in the webconfig file as detailed by several Stack Overflow answers--none of which worked to resolve the problem.

**How, and in what way, does the Microsoft update interfere with Crystal Reports 13 on the server?** My knowledge of the way updates interact with one another is limited, so I am not sure how I can fix Crystal Reports while keeping this update installed.